# Compress JSF 2.0 Ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to compress all JSF Ajax requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just turn on GZIP compression at servletcontainer level. How exactly to do that depends on the container used. In case of for example Tomcat you can do that by adding `compression="on"` to the [HTTP `<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) of interest in `/conf/server.xml`. You also need to ensure that `text/xml` is one of the default mime types in the `compressableMimeType` setting.